# Dollar Sign in RPG/AS400 variable name

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpg

I am looking at some code, some AS400 code; I see a variable declaration with a $ symbol in it. Does this have a special meaning?

```
D Q$test          S              8  0
```

Ostensibly this is a numeric variable 'test'; is Q$ a part of the actual name or does it have a special meaning for AS400/RPG.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has no special meaning to RPG, just part of the name.  Some programmers used some convention like those were local variables vs. those from database or display file but the meaning could be different in different companies.

Comment: And while a common practice in old code, it's considered a bad practice now-a-days since $ is not one of the invariant characters in EBCDIC.  So if you're trying to share code, folks who work in other languages have issues.